# Pandas creating new columns based on conditions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, partial-matches

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` is a dataframe with various columns and `df2` is a dataframe with only one column `col2`, which is a list of words.

It is obviously wrong, but my code so far is: `df1["col_new"] = df1[df1["col1"]].str.contains(df2["col2"])`

Basically, I want to create a new column called `col_new` in `df1` that has copied values from `col2` in `df2` if the values are partial matches to values in `col1` in `df1`.

For example, if `col2 = "apple"` and `col1 = "im.apple3"`, then I want to copy or assign the value `"apple"` to `col_new` and so on.

Another question I have is to find the index/position of second uppercase letter in a string in `col1` in `df1`.

I found a similar question on here and wrote this code: `df["sec_upper"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: re.research("[A-Z]+{2}",x).span())[1]` but I get an error saying "multiple repeat at position 6".

Can someone please help me out? Thank you in advance!

EDIT2: First problem solved. Can anyone please help me with the second problem?

EDIT1:

Example dataframes:

```
df1

col1             
im.apple3     
Cookiemm      
Hi_World123


df2

col2
apple
cookie
world
candy
soda
```

Expected output:

```
col1          new_col     sec_upper
im.apple3     apple       NaN
Cookiemm      cookie      NaN
Hi_World123   world       4
```

Comment: post example data expected output.

Comment: @Paul H Just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1['new_col'] = df1['col1'].str.lower().str.extract(f"({'|'.join(df2['col2'])})")
```

Output:

```
          col1 new_col
0    im.apple3   apple
1     Cookiemm  cookie
2  Hi_World123   world
```

Comment: I am getting syntax error. I think it has to do with brackets. Did you get any error?

Comment: Nvm. Figured it out. Thanks so much!